# Computing residues of $\cot(\pi z)/z(z+1)$ with symmetries

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I would like to know if there is a *quick* way of computing the residues of $$f(z) = \frac{\cot \pi z}{z(z+1)}$$at the points $z = 0$ and $z = -1$. They are double poles.

Expanding this in Laurent series I have: \begin{align} \frac{\cot \pi z}{z(z+1)} &= \frac{1}{z}\left(\frac{1}{\pi z}-\frac{\pi z}{3}-\frac{\pi^3z^3}{45}+\cdots\right)(1-z+z^2-z^3+z^4+\cdots) \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi z^2}-\frac{1}{\pi z}+\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{\pi}{3}+\cdots\end{align}
which gives: $${\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z(z+1)}, 0\right) = -\frac
1\pi.$$ My calculation above seemed quick, but computing Laurent series for $\cot$ is a pain. Also, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residue+cot%28pi+z%29%2F%28z%28z%2B1%29%29) gives:  $${\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z(z+1)},-1\right) = -\frac
1\pi,$$too, which makes me think that there is some symmetry to be explored here. At first I thought about some symmetry around the $x = -1/2$ axis, and the following plot suggests that it might be the case. However, we don't have quite a straight line, so I don't know how to apply this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without doing much work as follows. You can write:

$$\frac{1}{z(z+1)} = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z+1}$$

Also, if we have some analytic function $f(z)$ with simple zeros at $z_k$, then its  logarithmic derivative $g(z)$ will have poles of order 1 with residues equal to 1 at $z_k$. If we take $f(z) = \sin(\pi z)$ then the zeros are at integer $z$ and the logarithmic derivative is $g(z) = \pi\cot(\pi z)$ which up to the factor of $\pi$ is the cot function in your problem.

We also know that $g(z)$ is an odd function, the first term in the Laurent expansion is $\frac{1}{z}$, the next term is $\mathcal{O}(z)$. This implies that the residue at $z = 0$ won't get a contribution from the $\frac{1}{z}$ term, so only the $-\frac{1}{1+z}$ term  can make a contribution. That contribution is  equal to the value of this term at $z=0$ times the residue of the cot function at zero, which yields $-\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: I think I understand. Mimicking your argument, I'd say that the residue at $-1$ would be the value of the term $\frac{1}{z}$ at $-1$ times the residue of the $\cot$ function at zero, which yields $-\frac{1}{\pi}$ too. Thanks, this works fine. Just to clarify, about stating that the final residue would be the value of something evaluated at the point times  the residue of the initial function.. is there some result stated about this situation, or it was something along the lines of "just look at it"? I've never seen any result like this. +1 of course.

Comment: @IvoTerek If we write the function as f(z) g(z) and f(z) has a pole of order 1  at z = 0 while g(z) is analytic there then in the Laurent expansion of the product, to get the 1/z term, you must take the 1/z term from f(z) and the constant term from g(z), therefore the residue will be the residue of f(z) multiplied by g(0).

Comment: @CountIblis If the Laurent expansion for $g$ has terms that are of "lower order" (e.g., $z^{-2}$, $z^{-3}$), then the higher order terms in $f$ will be implicated in the residues of $fg$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Indeed, so we are using that cot only has simple poles.

Comment: I carried out some computations. Check it out: $$\begin{align} {\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z(z+1)},-1\right) &= {\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z},-1\right) - {\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z+1},-1\right) \\ &= {\rm Res}(\cot \pi z, -1) \frac{1}{z}\bigg|_{z=-1} - {\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z+1},-1\right) \\ &= -\frac{1}{\pi} -  {\rm Res}\left(\frac{\cot \pi z}{z+1},-1\right) . \end{align}$$Similar computation gave the result for the residue at $0$ because $\cot \pi z = \frac{1}{\pi z} + {\cal O}(z)$, but how can we get rid of that term above? I don't think a parity argument will

Comment: work here. About the remark of lower order terms of $g$, I don't think that this is a problem in general, we said that $g(z)$ was analytic at the point..

Comment: @IvoTerek If you put z = -1 + u then that second term becomes cot(pi u)/u

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that periodicity nails it here. $$\cot \pi z = \frac{1}{\pi z}+ {\rm O}(z) \implies \cot \pi z = \cot\pi(z+1) = \frac{1}{\pi(z+1)} + {\rm O}(z+1),$$so $$\frac{\cot \pi z}{z+1} = \frac{1}{\pi(z+1)^2} + {\rm O}(1) $$and the residue is zero. Thanks a lot. I found this discussion most enlightening.

Comment: @IvoTerek This is a nice problem to work on! There is actually another method you can try. If you consider the contour integral over a big circle of radius R with the center the origin, then for R to infinity the integral will tend to zero. This means that the sum of all the residues will be zero. But the sum of all the residues is up to a factor of 1/pi, also equal to the summation of 1/z - 1/(z+1) for integer z except where this is singular, plus the residues where the fraction has singularities.  The summation is easily calculated (it's a telescoping summation).

Comment: This integral showed up trying to compute that summation. Telescoping it gives $1$ as a result, but the point of the exercise was exactly to practice with the integral :-)